# Python can't find class even though the import was successful

Tags: python

I have some folder: `/home/tom/my_module`.
In my_module directory I have:
`__init__.py` (empty file)
`my_class.py`

```
class HelloWorldExample(object):
    @staticmethod
    def someMethod():
      print("test")
```

Now, let's go into terminal terminal:

`cd ~ 
python`

And then, in python shell:
`import my_module` succedeed. However, I can't type something like:
`x= HelloWorldExample()`
nor
`HelloWorldExample.someMethod()`  because python can't find this class.
Any ideas?

Comment: `from my_module.my_class import HelloWorldExample` after this `x = HelloWorldExample()`

Comment: or, after the import, just use`x=my_module.HelloWorldExample()`

Comment: Is it possible to create such `__init__.py` such that it would be sufficient to do `import my_module`?

Answer (score 1):

When doing `import my_module` you're importing the module and it will be available as `my_module`.

If you want to access something defined in your module you will need to access it on the module ex: `my_module.thing_in_my_module`.

In your example that would translate to:

```
import my_module

x = my_module.HelloWorldExample()
```

But you could also do:

```
from my module import HelloWorldExample

x = HelloWorldExample()
```

This imports the class directly rather than the module.

See **https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages** for more information on packages and imports.