# Python can't use constructor of a class imported from another python file

Tags: python, class, oop, import

I constructed a Tree class in one python file named "tree.py", which has the codes below:

```
class Tree(object):
"""
A class representing a (non-null) tree with a root
node and some number of child subtrees (which will,
themselves, be instances of Tree)
"""

def __init__(self, k=None, v=None):
    
    self.key = k
    self.value = v 
    
    self.children = []
```

and then I imported it in the current file (a different file) and tried to construct a tree object, like this:

```
import tree
Tree("abc", 10)
```

which caused the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-aa7d7074ded5> in <module>
----> 1 Tree("abc", 10)

NameError: name 'Tree' is not defined
```

I thought I already imported class Tree?? Not sure why I can't construct a Tree object.
Thank you!

Comment: You imported the `tree` _module_. Try `from tree import Tree` to import the class _from_ the module. Or use it as `tree.Tree` with your current import.

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python can't find class even though the import was successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804422/python-cant-find-class-even-though-the-import-was-successful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just imported the 'tree.py' as a module. Try  `tree.Tree`  ,or for better syntax: `from tree import Tree`.

Answer (score -1):

The first letter of the tree in your import statement  should be capitalized

Comment: The import statement isn't giving an error. Python can find the `tree` module (it's in the `tree.py` file).

Comment: yeah so when I types "import tree" in python it passed without error.